# IndexError: index 5407 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to python and neural network

This is a part of my code:

```
y = [[tag2idx[w[1]] for w in s] for s in sentences]

y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, padding="post", value=tag2idx["O"])


y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=n_tags) for i in y]
```

This is the error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lam/.PyCharm2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 79, in <module>
    y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=n_tags) for i in y]
  File "C:/Users/lam/.PyCharm2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    y = [to_categorical(i, num_classes=n_tags) for i in y]
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 34, in to_categorical
    categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
IndexError: index 5407 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8
```

Comment: Your `n_tags` is probably smaller than the size of the vocabulary. This is essentially what the error means. You are passing in an index `5407` but the `to_categorical` has been set a `num_classes` less than that (I am assuming it's set to `8`)

Comment: Can you explain more? like what should I do? y has 5600 words and 8 classes.

Comment: If you have 5600 words, that's what num_classes should be. If you are new to text processing in Keras, you might want to follow a tutorial and learn the exact mechanics.

Comment: They are 5600 but not distinct, they are only 8 distinct words.

Comment: But what the error is saying is that it encountered the ID 5407 and since the num_classes = 8, it cannot convert that to a categorical vector. Therefore see if the max vocabulary ID is 8 not something bigger.

Comment: I found what cause the exception, it was something with `tag2idx`. Thank you!